# wp_query with custom post type only returning last posted

Tags: wp-query

i am using wp_query to get posts for a custom post type but it is only returning the most recently posted item.  This is both in the returned object and within the loop:

```
$wp_query = new WP_Query('post_type=events');
```

Any ideas what is happening?

Comment: Do not use `$wp_query` as variable, you are breaking the main query object. Also, the query defaults to the radingnsetting in back end when it comes to posts per page. If you need any other amount of posts, you explicitely need to set the `posts_per_page` parameter

Answer (score 0):

Using `$wp_query` as your variable is a bad idea as it is something WordPress uses itself. For returning as many results as you would like you can use `posts_per_page` in your query. There are [many more parameters](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Parameters) you can query with in WordPress.

```
$custom_wp_query = new WP_Query('posts_per_page=10&post_type=events');
```